# remove first element from array and return the array minus the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```js
var myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];

//removes the first element of the array, and returns that element.
alert(myarray.shift());
//alerts "item 1"

//removes the last element of the array, and returns that element.
alert(myarray.pop());
//alerts "item 4"
```

1. How to remove the first array but return the array minus the first element
2. In my example i should get `"item 2", "item 3", "item 4"` when i remove the first element

Comment: `alert(array.slice(1))` or `array.shift(); alert(array);`

Comment: @Thomas when i use `myarray.shift()` returns `"item 1"` what i want is return `"item 2", "item 3", "item 4"`

Comment: Please read the whole code I wrote, using `shift()`

Comment: If you need to create new array without first element then use slice.

Comment: If you need to modify existed array and return it. then write your own function.

Comment: Just to add one more to the mix :) With destructuring: `[,...myarray] = myarray;`

Comment: @Arnial If you want to edit the original array you don't need to write an own function, use `splice` instead.

Comment: `var arr = [1,2,3]; var exceptLast = arr.reverse().slice(1).reverse(); // not an efficient solution`

Answer (score 277, accepted):

This should remove the first element, and then you can return the remaining:

```js
var myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];
    
myarray.shift();
alert(myarray);
```

As others have suggested, you could also use slice(1);

```js
var myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];
  
alert(myarray.slice(1));
```

Comment: Note that `slice(1)` *doesn't* "remove the first element" from the array. Instead, it creates a **new** array with shallow copies of all of the values from the array except the first.

Comment: Useful to use slice(1) if you have an array of arrays.

Answer (score 98):

Why not use ES6?

```js
 var myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];
 const [, ...rest] = myarray;
 console.log(rest)
```

Comment: I like this idea, except that first it's going to be an unused constant.

Comment: Can fix that using `const [,...rest] = myarray` =O =D

Comment: Love this because it does not modifiy the initial array ref and it makes the PR reviewer go ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How does this work sir ??

Answer (score 7):

**Try this**

```
    var myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];

    //removes the first element of the array, and returns that element apart from item 1.
    myarray.shift(); 
    console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: did you try this one?see my updated question with snippet it will return `"item 1"`

Answer (score 6):

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

array2 = array.slice(1,array.length); //arrayExceptfirstValue

console.log(array2);
```

I over through all the notable answers. I am pointing out a different answer. It works for me. I hope it will help you

```
array.slice(1,array.length)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in one line with lodash [`_.tail`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#tail):

```js
var arr = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];
console.log(_.tail(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

`myarray.splice(1)` will remove the first item from the array … and return the updated array (`['item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']` in your example).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is this:

```
const myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];
const [, ...arrayYouNeed] = myarray;
console.log(arrayYouNeed);
```

The original `array` is untouched and you can use the `arrayYouNeed` wherever you need it.

If you wanna know how it works look up 'deconstructing arrays'!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a single statement solution, you can filter out by index. Keep in mind that this does not modify the array though.

```js
var myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];

console.log(myarray.filter((_, i) => i !== 0))
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use array.slice(0,1) // First index is removed and array is returned.

Comment: FIrst index is not removed, a copy is created without the first element. The original array is not modified.

Comment: Also, slice(0,1) will return an array containing *the first item only*. Instead you need to call slice(1) to get an array containing *all but the first* item, as in the accepted answer

Comment: You probably meant array.splice(0,1), not "slice". Note the "p" letter. As a side note, I consider this a bad naming convention by js where two methods differ by just 1 letter and both methods give you sort of opposite results.