# How to implement a function that takes an array and some other arguments then removes the other arguments from that array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please guys, this is an exercise (exercise 04) from Odin Project. I don't know if there is anything wrong with the code below, it keeps failing the 'npm test' (a test in the terminal) but then i checked it with console.log and it worked.

```
const removeFromArray= function(...args) {
    const array = args[0];
        const newArray = [];
             array.forEach((item) => {
                 if(!args.includes(item)) {
                      newArray.push(item);  
        }
        });
        return newArray;
    };
```

Comment: You haven't included any code here. We need to see what you've attempted in order to guide you.

Comment: Hey dear! I did include a javascript code snippet

Comment: Failing how?  Sorry, you haven't given us enough information to go on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to achieve the required result.

We filter any element from the input array if it is present in the `itemsToRemove` array.

```js
function removeFromArray(array, itemsToRemove) {
    return array.filter(element => !itemsToRemove.includes(element));
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let itemsToRemove = [2,4,6];

console.log(removeFromArray(array, itemsToRemove))
```

We can do this in a more efficient manner if `itemsToRemove` is very large, using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
function removeFromArray(array, itemsToRemove) {
    const itemsToRemoveSet = new Set(itemsToRemove);
    return array.filter(element => !itemsToRemoveSet.has(element));
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let itemsToRemove = [2,4,6];

console.log(removeFromArray(array, itemsToRemove))
```

Comment: Thank you @Terry. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that I have not understood the question very well. But JS has built-in functions that serve the purpose

Array map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Array filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

But from what I see in the code you have to remove the first element from the array.

I suggest you take a look at this question

[remove first element from array and return the array minus the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096687/remove-first-element-from-array-and-return-the-array-minus-the-first-element)

Comment: Thank you @Andrea. The function actually has array and other arguments as parameters, so my aim is to return just the array, I don't think the array methods shift(), slice() or pop can work for it. I stand to be corrected though.